# Cognito authorization and API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use Cognito authorization with calling API Gateway function from Javascript. My setup is Chalice framework for API Gateway/Lambdas and the Cognito Built-In sign-in page.

For the built-in sign-in page I set response_type=token and then I copied the token I got back with id_token and tried pasting it into the Test Authorizer in API Gateway and it returns "Unauthorized request". Should this work?

Comment: According to the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) your scenario should work. Are you passing your id_token via the "Authorization" header to the API Gateway?

Comment: @DenisWeerasiri tried a few ways. I tried setting "Authorization" header to "Bearer [id_token value]". I also tried going to Authorizers in the API Gateway console and clicking "Test" and then entering the id_token value. Both of them return Unauthorized.